# How to append in list in Python without overwriting?

Tags: python

```
country = ["Denmark", "Croatia", "Britian", "Canada"]
for idx, val in enumerate(country):
    d = []
    d.append(idx)
    print(d)
```

I'm learning how to append index in a list but i keep overwriting my iteration. Can you please help?

Comment: Don't re-create the list in the loop with `d = []`. Put that line above the `for` loop.

Comment: You're creating a new `d` in every iteration. Mode `d = []` outside the for loop

Comment: Consider defining the variable `d` outside the for loop. This would ensure that `d` doesn't get reset in every iteration.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both, as well as some other completely spurious tags. Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
country = ["Denmark", "Croatia", "Britian", "Canada"]
d = []
for i,v in enumerate(country):
    d.append(v)


for i in range(0,4):
    print(country[i])
```

**Output**

Denmark

Croatia

Britian

Canada

Answer (score 0):

```
country = ["Denmark", "Croatia", "Britian", "Canada"]
d = []
for idx, val in enumerate(country):
    d.append(idx)
    print(d)
```

You need to put the definition of `d` outside of the loop, otherwise on each iteration d becomes an empty list again.

Answer (score 0):

d is being instantiated as null each time you enter the loop, define it outside your loop

```
country = ["Denmark", "Croatia", "Britian", "Canada"]
d = []
for idx, val in enumerate(country):
   
    d.append(idx)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up is creating list d every time it iterates through the loop.

To fix this, you want to declare the list before entering the loop. That way it isn't making a new copy of d with no elements every time.

```
country = ["Denmark", "Croatia", "Britain", "Canada"]
#list initialized with nothing in it
d = []
for idx, val in enumerate(country):
    #list declaration here means we make a new copy of d every time we go through the loop
    d.append(idx)

#I moved the print outside the loop so we don't print on every iteration
print(d)
```